# How the posts and categories connected each other in wp 4.1.1?

Tags: categories

There are no post_category field in table wp_posts in my wp4.1.1 .
How the posts and categories connected each other in wp 4.1.1?

```
mysql> show columns from wp_posts;


+-----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type                | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| ID                    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| post_author           | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
| post_date             | datetime            | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| post_date_gmt         | datetime            | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| post_content          | longtext            | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| post_title            | text                | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| post_excerpt          | text                | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| post_status           | varchar(20)         | NO   |     | publish             |                |
| comment_status        | varchar(20)         | NO   |     | open                |                |
| ping_status           | varchar(20)         | NO   |     | open                |                |
| post_password         | varchar(20)         | NO   |     |                     |                |
| post_name             | varchar(200)        | NO   | MUL |                     |                |
| to_ping               | text                | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| pinged                | text                | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| post_modified         | datetime            | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| post_modified_gmt     | datetime            | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| post_content_filtered | longtext            | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| post_parent           | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
| guid                  | varchar(255)        | NO   |     |                     |                |
| menu_order            | int(11)             | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| post_type             | varchar(20)         | NO   | MUL | post                |                |
| post_mime_type        | varchar(100)        | NO   |     |                     |                |
| comment_count         | bigint(20)          | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
+-----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
23 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not just happening in Wordpress 4.1.1, but for all version that I know of from version 3.0 when I started on Wordpress

Posts and taxonomy terms are stored in different tables in the db, posts in `wp_posts` and taxonomy terms in `wp_term_taxonomy`. To create a relationship between terms and posts, there is another table called `wp_term_relationships`. This table holds the post ID which relates back to the `wp_posts` table, and creates a relationship to the appropriate term through the term ID which relates back to the `wp_term_taxonomy` table.

This is how Wordpress knows which terms are connected to which post.

For additional info, check out [this article](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-and-working-with-relationships-between-data-in-wordpress--cms-20632) by tutsplus :-)